# How to check non-c files in vim using syntastic and ycm without saving them?

Tags: matlab, vim, vim-plugin, syntastic

I am using `vim` with the plugins [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) and [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) for autocompletion and syntax checking .

If I am editing C or C++ files, syntax errors are marked after two seconds of in inactivity.
When editing MATLAB files, syntax checks (using `mlint`) are done only after I save the file.

I know that the interval of two seconds is regulated via `updatetime`, which means checks of C files are performed after the swap file updates.

How can I get the same behaviour for source files of other programming languages (especially for MATLAB)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background checking of C-family languages is a product of YCM's syntastic intergration (see `:h youcompleteme-syntastic-integration` and `:h g:ycm_register_as_syntastic_checker`).  I don't see an easy way to set YCM to do that with other file types or to set syntastic to auto-update.

You might be able to dig around in YCM's code to see how they do it, then either extend that to work with MATLAB files or write a small plugin.

Comment: Thank you. Since I do not know anything about vim plugin scripting, I will probably not do this for now. But thank you for the information.